# Azure VM: Permission Denied

Tags: azure, ubuntu

I am trying to clone a git repository in an azure VM, although I don't have any permissions to `mkdir` in `/var/www/etc`. I could use `sudo` but then `git clone` would refuse my public key, pretty much locked in here.

I have added my user to the sudoers file, I have attempted to change the permissions on my user using `sudo usermod -a -G sudo username`, still no luck. I have rebooted the server on both occasions, but still receiving permission denied when running `mkdir`, and git clone fails without `sudo`.

I am unsure what routes I have left? When deploying Vms with GCP, AWS, and many more I have never had the issue with permissions.

Comment: When all else fails, resort to git magic: sudo mkdir <blah>, cd <blah>, git init, git pull <git repo>.

Comment: or you can fiddle with the folder permissions with chown

Comment: You can try to add your current user to the root group or you can set your current user as the owner of the path `/etc/www/etc` with the root permission.